# Build/deploy Vue.js project through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, vue.js

I am new to Jenkins but have done a few builds/deployment jobs of .net project successfully.

Now I am trying to build/deploy Vue.js project through Jenkins but just cannot get through...

I can build the project directly on a server using command prompt. It builds and creates files for deployment in a right directory.

When I am trying to do it in Jenkins job (using the same npm commands) it does not give any error messages, says it built successfully but it does NOT create any files for deployment.

Does anybody encounter this problem? Did anybody build Vue js project through Jenkins? Any help appreciated. Thanks!

In execute windows batch command I run:

```
cd myworkdirectory
npm install
npm run build
```

Answer (score 2):

Not too complex, as I found.

1. Create freestyle project.
2. In section `Source Code Management` please define your repository.
3. In section `Build Triggers` please define triggers
4. In section `Build` define either `Execute Windows batch command` or `Execute shell` within sections like (my choice in the moment - windows):

   1. `git checkout develop`
   2. `npm -g install`
   3. `npm run build`
   4. `del /s /f /q c:\applications\frontend-app-build\*.*`
   5. `for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b c:\applications\frontend-app-build\') do rd /s /q c:\applications\frontend-app-build\%%f`
   6. `robocopy dist c:\applications\frontend-app-build\ /E`

Comment: And that will also help: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2015/10/triggering-jenkins-builds-by-url/